# Directions for more than one location on Google Maps API v. 3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556312/google-maps-v3-create-routes-between-two-points), I was able to successfully map two locations using this source code below.  How do I add a third or fourth location as a waypoint in between the beginning and end locations?  I tried to add a second end point but that did not work?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <title></title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <style>
       html, body, #map {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         height: 100%;
       }
     </style>
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var Center=new google.maps.LatLng(18.210885,-67.140884);
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var properties = {
    center:Center,
    zoom:20,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};

map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), properties);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
position:Center,
animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
});

marker.setMap(map);
Route();
}

function Route() {

var start = new google.maps.LatLng(18.210885,-67.140884);
var end =new google.maps.LatLng(18.211685,-67.141684);
var request = {
origin:start,
destination:end,
travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
 };
 directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
} else { alert("couldn't get directions:"+status); }
});
} 

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
</script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="map"></div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: When you say "add a third point", what are you trying to do?  Add a third location as a waypoint between the existing start and end?  Add a third location and find the directions from start to new location and from end to new location?

Comment: Yes, add a third waypoint between the current beginning and end points.  Sorry, I'll update the question to be more clear too.

Comment: Did you try [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints)?

Comment: Yes @geocodezip, I'm having trouble making sense of it.

Comment: What is the "third point" you are trying to add to `var start = new google.maps.LatLng(18.210885,-67.140884); var end =new google.maps.LatLng(18.211685,-67.141684);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you would be comfortable to use a [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?hl=en#Polylines).

Try this variant:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Complex polylines</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var poly;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(18.210885,-67.140884);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 20,
    center: chicago,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var lineCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.210885,-67.140884),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.211685,-67.141114),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.211685,-67.141684)
  ];


    var polyOptions = {
      path: lineCoordinates,
      strokeColor: '#dd4b39',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 5
    }
    poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
    poly.setMap(map);

    for (i = 0; i <= lineCoordinates.length; i++)
    {
        if (lineCoordinates[i] !== undefined)
        {
            new google.maps.Marker({
              position: lineCoordinates[i],
              title: 'some title',
              map: map
            });
        }
    }
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is sweet...totally a different direction and worked GREAT...thanks!